# Concatenating at the end of a string - Python

Tags: python, string, file

I have a file that basically looks like this:

```
atom
coordinateX coordinateY coordinateZ
atom
coordinateX coordinateY coordinateZ
...
```

I'm trying to add the atom number (starting from 0) so that my file would look like this:

```
atom0
coordinateX coordinateY coordinateZ
atom1
coordinateX coordinateY coordinateZ
...
```

Here's my code and my problem:

```
readFile = open("coordinates.txt", 'r')
writeFile = open("coordinatesFormatted.txt", 'w')
index = 1
counter = 0

for lineToRead in readFile:
    lineToRead = lineToRead.lstrip()
    if index % 2 == 0:
        counter = counter + 1
        lineToRead+=str(counter) 
    writeFile.write(lineToRead)
    index = index+1

readFile.close()
writeFile.close()

f = open('coordinatesFormatted.txt','r')
temp = f.read()
f.close()

f = open('coordinatesFormatted.txt', 'w')
f.write("0")
f.write(temp)
f.close()
```

Instead of having my desired output after I run my code I get this:

```
0atom
coordinateX coordinateY coordinateZ
1atom
coordinateX coordinateY coordinateZ
...
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 combined problems which makes a funny combination: a odd/even problem on your counter and the use of `lstrip` instead of `strip`: `strip` removes the linefeed that shift your lines.

I rewrote your code, removing the last part which is now useless and now it works as expected.

```
readFile = open("coordinates.txt", 'r')
writeFile = open("coordinatesFormatted.txt", 'w')
index = 1
counter = -1

for lineToRead in readFile:
    lineToRead = lineToRead.strip()
    if index % 2:
        counter += 1
        lineToRead+=str(counter)  # append counter to atom without linefeed
    writeFile.write(lineToRead+"\n") # write line, adding the linefeed again
    index += 1

readFile.close()
writeFile.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Running two counters in your loop can get quite messy. And you're not properly *stripping* those lines.

The following does what you want replacing `index` and `count` with an [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) object. The new line character is added to the line at the `write` method:

```
from itertools import count

c = count() # set up a counter that starts from zero
with open('coordinates.txt') as f, open('coordinatesFormatted.txt', 'w') as fout:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if  line == 'atom':
            line += str(next(c)) # get the next item from the counter
        fout.write(line + '\n')
```

Comment: Your solution is more pythonic than mine. upvoting it :) Even if beginners may prefer FORTRAN-like stuff to get ahold of the language.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I didn't want to post after you answered, but I felt the two counters were unnecessary. Your explanation was however great

Comment: you were right to do so. I answered as quickly as I could. And with your post I'm the one who learned something about itertools. Plus we are here to show people how to code properly, not only solving the problems.